How do I launch a GUI application with systemd after wake-from-suspend?
On my old Ubuntu 22.04 machine (under Wayland) I was able to modify this solution to create the file /etc/systemd/system/my_user_script.service and launch the Thunderbird flatpak after waking my computer from suspend:
[Unit]
Description=Open Thunderbird
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/flatpak run org.mozilla.Thunderbird
User=my_user_name
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

On my new Ubuntu 24.04 install (under Wayland) I repeated the same thing but it no longer works. After starting and enabling the service file I issue the command sudo systemctl status my_user_script.service and I get:
× my_user_script.service - Open Thunderbird
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_user_script.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-05-23 12:34:38 EDT; 38s ago
   Duration: 293ms
    Process: 259084 ExecStart=/bin/flatpak run org.mozilla.Thunderbird (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 259084 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 53ms

May 23 12:34:38 OEM-24-04 systemd[1]: Started my_user_script.service - Open Thunderbird.
May 23 12:34:38 OEM-24-04 systemd[1]: my_user_script.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 23 12:34:38 OEM-24-04 systemd[1]: my_user_script.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

journalctl -b -u my_user_script.service tells me the same:
May 23 12:34:38 OEM-24-04 systemd[1]: Started my_user_script.service - Open Thunderbird.
May 23 12:34:38 OEM-24-04 systemd[1]: my_user_script.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 23 12:34:38 OEM-24-04 systemd[1]: my_user_script.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

How do I launch a GUI application with systemd after wake-from-suspend? It's my understanding this can be "quirky" and I'm discovering that now. It's also my understanding a user service will not work:

sleep.target is specific to system services. The reason is, sleep.target is not a magic target that automatically gets activated when going to sleep. It's just a regular target that puts the system to sleep – so the 'user' instances of course won't have an equivalent. (And unfortunately the 'user' instances currently have no way to depend on systemwide services.)


There are quite a few more environment variables involved in starting apps – I'd say you were lucky that it worked with just a hardcoded DISPLAY value (which Wayland does not even use). For example, your service ought to have XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, and WAYLAND_DISPLAY, and so on. It's also a bit messy to have apps running in a service cgroup in general (though not inherently a problem, just messy).
If you want to continue with your "system service" approach (assuming your logs show that it is still being triggered at the correct time), then the best way is to let systemd --user start the app for you. It's already responsible for starting a good chunk of your GUI, and it has an API to start arbitrary processes which can be called using systemd-run --user:

As you're already manually setting environment variables:
User=<my_user_name>
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/<my_uid>
ExecStart=systemd-run --user --service --collect <program>


For reference if you want to use this from other contexts; sufficiently recent systemd-run can handle the user-switching itself:
systemd-run -M <my_user_name>@.host --user --service --collect <program>



(You will probably need the --service option in your case; --scope won't work as it won't have privileges to move the process out of a service cgroup.)
Following this procedure, you can actually have a user service that runs Thunderbird (after all, literally what systemd-run does is generate an in-memory service)... it just needs to be started by something – you won't be able to simply hook it up to a user-level .target for this. So, for instance, if you had written a thunderbird.service, you could replace "systemd-run…" in the above example with "systemctl --user start thunderbird".
The other approach is to write some user-level program that listens to systemd-logind's "prepare for sleep" / "returned from sleep" D-Bus signals and runs Thunderbird whenever that happens.
